# Listview is not showing proper result due to some malfunctioning in selecting data from sqlite database

Tags: android, select, android-sqlite

I create an application in which,I'm retrieving the data from sqllite database,but that data is not coming properly whole of the data is coming in single `TextView` and `onClick()` whole of the data is selected.I mean, I only want to select the particular data so as to open in new `activity` to update it,but whole data is getting selected.it is not in a proper format.what to do, to get the proper data

`Campaign_Details.java`

```
package com.example.smscampaign;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Campaign_Details extends Activity {

 ListView listview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_demostration);
         listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
         listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        TextView txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textnum1);
        DataBaseHelp info = new DataBaseHelp(this);
        info.open();
        String data = info.getData();
    //  String r[] = {info.KEY_NAME , info.KEY_SCALE};
        info.close();
        String [] values1= data.split("\n");
        int t = values1.length;
        txt.setText(Integer.toString(t));

        String[] values = new String[] { data };

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            list.add(values[i]);
        }
        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }

        });
    }

    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            String item = getItem(position);
            return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nextPage:
            Intent i= new Intent(Campaign_Details.this,SmsSend.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

`activity_list_demostration.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="3" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textcolour"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="@drawable/green_circle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Active Campaign"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#4AE56B" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textnum1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
                android:background="@drawable/green_badge"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" 0 "
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            >
        </TextView>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="3" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textcolour"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_circle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Closed Campaign"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textnum2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_badge"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" 0 "
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

`Demo.java`

```
package com.example.smscampaign;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Demo extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final String[] values;
private final Context context;
    public Demo(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context,R.layout.list, values);
        this.context=context;
        this.values= values;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent,false);
        TextView txt=(TextView) rowview.findViewById (R.id.text1);
        //ImageView img=(ImageView) rowview.findViewById (R.id.icon);
        txt.setText(values[position]);
        //changing icon

        return rowview;
    }
}
```

`list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`DataBaseHandler.java`

```
package com.example.smscampaign;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class DataBaseHandler{

    public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="person_name";
    public static final String KEY_SCALE="scale_person";
    public static final String KEY_Contacts="Contacts_person";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="Himani";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="savedTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

    private DbHelper ourHepler;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  " +
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_SCALE + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"  + KEY_Contacts + ")"
                    );
            }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public DataBaseHandler(Context c){
        ourContext=c;
    }


    public DataBaseHandler open() throws SQLException{
        ourHepler = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase=  ourHepler.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close()
    {
        ourHepler.close();
    }


    public long entryCreate(String name, String scale , String contacts) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_SCALE, scale);
        cv.put(KEY_Contacts, contacts);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv); 

    }


    public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE, KEY_Contacts};
        Cursor c=  ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, null, null, null, null, null);
        String run="";
        int iRow=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iScale=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCALE);
        int iMessage=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Contacts);
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
            run=run+c.getString(iRow)+ " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iScale) + " " + c.getString(iName) +"\n";
        }

        return run;
    }


    public String getScale(long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE , KEY_Contacts};
        Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col,KEY_ROWID + "-" + l, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String scale=c.getString(2);
            return scale;
        }
        return null;
    }


    public String getName(long l)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE , KEY_Contacts};
        Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col,KEY_ROWID + "-" + l, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String name=c.getString(1);
            return name;

        }
        return null;
    }
    public String getC0ntacts(long l)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE ,KEY_Contacts};
        Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col,KEY_ROWID + "-" + l, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String contacts=c.getString(3);
            return contacts;

        }
        return null;
    }

    public  void updateEntry(long lt, String mName, String mScale ,String mContatcs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          ContentValues cvUpdate=new ContentValues();   
          cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME,mName);
          cvUpdate.put(KEY_SCALE,mScale);
          cvUpdate.put(KEY_Contacts,mContatcs );
          ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE,  cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "-" + lt, null);
    }


    public void deleteEntry(long ltt) throws SQLException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + ltt,null);

    }
}
```

Actually the problem is data is retrieving in only single textbox..,different data with different rowid is not displaying in the different textbox in listview..,what should i do to separate the data by row id

```
final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            list.add(values[i]);
        }
```

giving the list at last in the adapter as a result whole of the data is viewing in single text box

Comment: Why do you have listview inside scrollview. is it needed that way.
ListView itself sufficient for scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In getData method your are concatenating all the data, modify it like this

```
public ArrayList<String> getData() {

    String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE, KEY_Contacts};
    Cursor c=  ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, null, null, null, null, null);
    String run="";
    int iRow=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iScale=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCALE);
    int iMessage=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Contacts);
    ArrayList<String> newList= new ArrayList<String>();
    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
     newList.add(c.getString(iRow)+ " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iScale) + " " + c.getString(iName));
    }

    return newList;
}
```

And in your activity

```
final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, info.getData());
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Change your array adapter constructor to accept ArrayList as argument like this

```
public class Demo extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final ArrayList<String> values=null;
private final Context context;
public Demo(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
    super(context,R.layout.list, values);
    this.context=context;
    this.values= values;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent,false);
    TextView txt=(TextView) rowview.findViewById (R.id.text1);
    //ImageView img=(ImageView) rowview.findViewById (R.id.icon);
    txt.setText(values.get(position));
    //changing icon

    return rowview;
}
```

}

Comment: but it is giving an error on stableArrayAdapter when i change it to info.getData();

Comment: The constructor Campaign_Details.StableArrayAdapter(Campaign_Details, int, String) is undefined

Comment: it is giving me error in this line final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, info.getData());

Comment: What id the use of Demo class here ?

Comment: What is the return value of getData() method , is it String or ArrayList<String> ?

Comment: and return type of getData is String

Comment: i didnt made demo class id here .., it is using final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list); and define that below the Camoaign_details –

Comment: Actually the problem is data is retrieving in only single textbox..,different data with different rowid is not displaying in the different textbox in listview..,what should i do to separate the data by row id

Comment: Change the return type of getData() to ArrayList<String> as specified in the Answer

Comment: Are you getting the same error as before ?
The constructor Campaign_Details.StableArrayAdapter(Campaign_Details, int, String) is undefined

Answer (score 2):

You have error in your create table syntax,

```
KEY_Contacts
```

You forgot to define data type for above column.

Your correct syntax should be like follow,

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
 {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
          KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  " +
          KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
          KEY_SCALE + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"  + 
          KEY_Contacts + "TEXT NOT NULL )"                  // Change at this line.
       );
 }
```

Note : After this change, you need to delete your old application from emulator/real device and then start installing a fresh will give you proper result.

Comment: it is not the problem..,my problem is whole data is selected at a time,but i want to get single data selected at a time

Comment: @user3359315 are you able to listdown the datas ? I think your table is not created.

Comment: @user3359315 seriously you are getting the data ? because your create table syntax is not right, hence there should not be any table. Can you tell me what is the data type of `KEY_Contacts` column ?

Comment: It's perfectly ok (not an error) to not specify any datatype for a column.

Comment: @laalto, ok so by default which datatype it is taking ?

Comment: @Kedarnath In sqlite any column (except `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`) can have value of any type. The declared types are just suggestions called type affinity. If a type is not declared, `NUMERIC` is the default. Read more: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html